# Class is not populated when extends from an abstract in Dropwizard

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, dropwizard

HI I have two classes in java, I'm using dropwizard framework.

My class is extending from an abstract class, but the properties that are in the abstract class are not being populated.

```
     public abstract class Person(){
       @Column( name = "name" )
       protected String name;

       @Column( name = "lastname" )
       protected  String lastName;

       public void setName(String name){
          this.name = name
       }

      public String getName(){
         return this.name;
      }

      public void setLastName( String lastName ){
         this.lastName = lastName;
      }

      public String getLastName(){
         return this.lastName;
       }
    }
```

And Here is my class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users" )
    public class User extends Person(){
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
      @Column( name = "idUser" )
      protected Long Id;

      @Column( name = "username" )
      protected String userName;

      @Column( name = "password" )
      protected String password;

      public void setUserName( String userName){
         this.userName = userName;
      }

      public String getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
      }

      public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
      }

      public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
      }
    }
```

When I try to populate the class only populate the properties that are contained in `User` class the properties of `Person` are null.

This is my DAO

```
    public class UsersDao extends AbstractDAO<User>{
           @Inject
            public UsersDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
             super(sessionFactory);
            }

            public List<User> fetchUsers(){
              return list(criteria());
            }
       }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `extends Person()` should be `extends Person`, I think you need a `@MappedSuperclass` on the parent class

Comment: ^ Same with the class declaration: `public abstract class Person {`, no parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Your class extends Person **()** with parentheses, when in fact it should not have the parenthesis, you should annotate your parent class with **@MappedSuperClass**